# Swift 3: How can I remove the extra space from the TableView?

Tags: uitableview, swift3, uiwebview, autolayout

I have a webview on the tableview, and on each cell I have some extra blank space after the phone numbers and email/ website addresses. So how can I remove/ delete the extra blank space from the cell to make it look bit better.

the code what I have is this:

```
self.heightOfTheCell = CGFloat(((heightMul)*32)+4)
```

I am not too sure how to play up with these numbers.

Please find the screenshot attached.

[image]

```
 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {

    if indexPath.section == 0
    {
        if heightOfTheCell != nil
        {
            return heightOfTheCell
        }else{
            return UITableViewAutomaticDimension
        }
    }
    else{
        return UITableViewAutomaticDimension
    }



}


func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, estimatedHeightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {


        return UITableViewAutomaticDimension
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I do it.

First setup properly the constraints for the cells.

then on your viewController

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return UITableViewAutomaticDimension
}


func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, estimatedHeightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return UITableViewAutomaticDimension
}
```

Comment: It seems the `heightOfTheCell` is making the heights constant, can you try to remove it and just the `UITableViewAutomaticDimension`?

If issue still occur, maybe there is a constraint in the cell that forces the heigh to a specific value.

By any means, here's where I learned to set the cell heights dynamically.
https://www.raywenderlich.com/129059/self-sizing-table-view-cells